# VBA: Copy multiple columns from a Sheet into one column from another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple columns with a specific distance between them and i want to copy all data into one column.

I have a variable `n=29`.

The distance between columns is allways 9.
the number of total columns is `n*(9+1)=290` witch corespond to column `"KD"`

The sheet with bellow data is named `"Importat"`

```
 |  B  |....|  L  |....|  V  |...| AF |..until.. |  KD  |
---------------------------------------------------------
1|
2|  10 |....| 79  |....| 21  |...| 41 |..........|  22  |
3|  13 |....| 55  |....| 51  |...|    |..........|  56  |
4|  16 |....|     |....|     |...|    |..........|  67  |
```

And the results must be like this in sheet `"COD+DATA"`

```
  |  K  |
 ---------
 1|     |
 2| 10  |
 3| 13  |
 4| 16  |
 5| 79  |
 6| 55  |
 7| 21  |
 8| 51  |
 9| 41  |
.......  
 x| 22  |
 y| 56  |
 z| 67  |
```

---

Any advice how can I do that ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? you could do this with a simple sub but would like to see what you have tried so far

Comment: I've tried when i copy the data from .xml columns, witch is opened one by one, but no succes. If i paste the query you don't understand because i have a lot of variables. I don't want all the query made by you, all I want is a hint ...thanks

Comment: By the way is not that simple as it seems

Comment: What I don't understand about your desired outcome is you have everything in 1 row, but the first 9 align with numbers I thought were row numbers, but then it goes to x y z. What data fills the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood your question but from what I understand, you have data in `Importat` sheet in a workbook. Data is in columns and columns are always separated by 9 columns (going all the way up to column `KD`). Below is one approach you can use:

```
Sub GetDataFromImportatSheet()

    Dim oIWS As Worksheet: Set oIWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Importat")
    Dim oCWS As Worksheet: Set oCWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("COD+DATA")
    Dim intLastColumn As Integer: intLastColumn = oIWS.Cells(2, oIWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim intLastRow As Integer
    Dim intColCounter As Integer
    Dim intCurRow As Integer
    Dim intCWSRow As Integer

    intCWSRow = 0

    For intColCounter = 2 To intLastColumn Step 9

        intLastRow = oIWS.Cells(oIWS.Rows.Count, intColCounter).End(xlUp).Row

        For intCurRow = 1 To intLastRow

            If Len(Trim(oIWS.Cells(intCurRow, intColCounter))) <> 0 Then

                intCWSRow = intCWSRow + 1
                oCWS.Cells(intCWSRow, "J").Value = intCWSRow
                oCWS.Cells(intCWSRow, "K").Value = oIWS.Cells(intCurRow, intColCounter)

            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I agree with @Thomas, your columns don't match your requirement of 9 columns apart but I've ignored your example and gone with '9 columns apart'

Comment: +1 your code looks good.  I you should use `For intColCounter = 2 To intLastColumn Step 9` instead of `intColCounter = intColCounter + 8`.  I personally use single letter variables for counters and indices.  When I see them I know they are counters.  If you get a change check out: [Refactored Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1awtf6RxROVnGiFStHtF3eTACSDasjOgtriL4XIIeCLc)  My use of `Target` is a little goofy, it may take away from the readibility of the code.

Comment: @ThomasInzina you are absolutely right. Totally forgot about the `Step` option: update code as per your spot. Cant get to the **Refactor Code** link from work but will have a look at it tonight

Answer (score 2):

You example data doesn't follow a consistent pattern.

[image]

```
Dim y As Long

For y = 2 To 300 Step 10
    Debug.Print Split(Columns(y).Address(False, False), ":")(0); ",";
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is reshape your data. I created a complex macro to do this both ways, list -> table and table -> list. Check it out: http://amitkohli.com/change-lists-into-tables-and-tables-into-lists/

You might have to create an intermediate table where all the data is next to eachother though, not 9 columns apart.